# Update variable value in variables Python file

Tags: python, variables, updates

I have a `variables.py` file with a key `TOKEN= 123456`. I need to update that value dynamically when ever it required.

The file Constants.py reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
variables.py
"""

TOKEN= 50
```

And `refresh_tok.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
refresh_tok.py
"""
import variables

def refresh_token():
    print(variables.TOKEN) // previous value 50
    change_constant(variables.TOKEN, 100)
    print(variables.TOKEN) // value I am expecting is 100 but it says 50


def change_constant(match_string, replace_string):
    read_file = open("variables.py", "rt")
    read_data = read_file.read()
    read_data = read_data.replace(match_string, replace_string)
    read_file.close()
    
    write_file = open("variables.py", "wt")
    write_file.write(read_data)
    write_file.close()
```

Value that I am expecting in 2nd print statement in refresh_tok.py is 100 but it is still on previous value and print 50 rather then 100.

Comment: I would suggest going through the `inspect` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html
maybe you'll find it helpful :)

Comment: Python source code is not the right place to store dynamic data. Use a JSON file or similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about the nature of computer programs.

Your `change_constant` function reads the source code from a file as a string, creates a new string which changes that source code, then writes that new string to the same file. This will **never** affect the module that you've loaded. This is very important to understand.

Instead, all you need to do is:

```
variables.TOKEN = new_value
```

Of course, this only affects the running process. If you need to *persist* these changes, then you need to choose some sort of persistence strategy, e.g. writing to a file. It is generally not a good practice to use python source code for this, instead, use some suitable serialization format, e.g. JSON, pickle, INI-like config files, YAML, etc etc (or even if it is very simple just a text file).